# Fire based on direction player is facing. Unity Javascript

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to fire a projectile based on the direction the game object is facing. Currently the script only permits the projectile to fire on a certain axis. Here is the line piece of code I need to be edited:

```
function Fire()
{
    lastShot = Time.time;
    Instantiate(laser, transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rotation property](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) of the Transform of the GameObject that you want the projectile to be facing in the same direction. So your code would be `Instantiate(laser, transform.position, transform.rotation);`